# eBay API call GetSellingManagerSoldListings returns 'start date or end date was missing or invalid' error

Tags: ebay-api

Below eBay API call always fails and gives an error

> Sorry, the start date or end date was missing or invalid date time
>   range.

The date format is correct. Any idea why it fails? Request is below

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <S:Header>
  <ebl:RequesterCredentials xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">
   <ebl:eBayAuthToken>my token</ebl:eBayAuthToken>
  </ebl:RequesterCredentials>
 </S:Header>
 <S:Body>
  <GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
   <Version>921</Version>
   <Archived>true</Archived>
   <Pagination>
    <EntriesPerPage>50</EntriesPerPage>
   </Pagination>
   <SaleDateRange>
    <TimeFrom>2015-02-26T07:05:40.027Z</TimeFrom>
    <TimeTo>2015-03-23T07:05:40.031Z</TimeTo>
   </SaleDateRange>
  </GetSellingManagerSoldListingsRequest>
 </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is "TimeTo"
It can't be now and have to be in the past. When I tried it it was 2 hours. So maybe it have somthing to do with the time zones.

This is a full working example with the [python api](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python) showing me the sales of the last 7 days:

```
    def get_unshipped(self, days_back=7):
        logger.debug("run get_unshipped()")
        date_from   = "{}.000Z".format(datetime.today() - timedelta(days_back))
        date_to     = "{}.000Z".format(datetime.today() - timedelta(minutes=120))
        api = Trading(config_file=os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), CONFIG_FILE), siteid=EBAY_SITE_ID)
        response = api.execute("GetSellingManagerSoldListings",
            {
            "Archived" : "false",
            "SaleDateRange" : {
                "TimeFrom" : str(date_from),
                "TimeTo"   : str(date_to)
                },
            }
        )
        print "sales found:", len(response.dict()["SaleRecord"])
```

Answer (score -1):

Using this API call, you can fetch records only within 120 days old.

Your date range is greater than 120 days.You should use Archived flag = true in the api call

refer
http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/GetSellingManagerSoldListings.html

Comment: Yes, I have written the archived flag.